# Angular ng-repeat value set

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use `ng-repeat` to construct table with radio buttons. The idea is to assign to each radio value the position of the object inside the original array (before ordering). When I use $index it assigns position in the ordered array and not original one. How to assign the right index,original one?

```
<tr class="restTable" data-ng-repeat="person in persons|orderBy:'name'">
<td> {{ person.name}}</td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="$parent.selectedPerson" value="{{$index}}"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `$index` is relative to to the **current element in the loop** and since you are sorting the array then you need to save a reference on the object itself from the directive (You can use `person.id` for example (If you have a unique `id`for each person)

Comment: the idea was once it is chosen to access it via `persons[$scope.selectedPerson]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment:

`$index` is relative **to to the current element** in the loop and since you are sorting the array then you need to save a reference on the object itself from the directive (You can use `person.id` for example (If you have a unique `id` for each person).

You can save a reference to the selected person via `ngValue`

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.selected = { person: null };
  $scope.persons = [{id: 1, name: "person1"}, {id: 2, name: "person2"}, {id: 3, name: "person3"}]; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <tr class="restTable" data-ng-repeat="person in persons|orderBy:'name'">
      <td> {{ person.name}}</td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="selected.person" ng-value="person"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <hr>
  <p>Selected Person:</p>
  <pre ng-bind="selected.person | json"></pre>
</div>
```

Here i'm using the `ngValue` and saving a reference to the selected object inside the loop. I don't care about the current position of the object because angularjs is making sure the selected person will be available in the controller via `$scope.selected.person`.

If you want to pre select a person, replace

```
$scope.selected = { person: null };
```

With

```
$scope.selected = { person: $scope.persons[1] };
```

But don't forget to declare `$scope.persons` before! Put that line **after** you declared the array in your controller. Example:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.persons = [{id: 1, name: "3person1"}, {id: 2, name: "1person2"}, {id: 3, name: "4person3"}]; 

  $scope.selected = { person: $scope.persons[1] };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <tr class="restTable" data-ng-repeat="person in persons|orderBy:'name'">
      <td> {{ person.name}}</td>
      <td> <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="selected.person" ng-value="person"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <hr>
  <p>Selected Person:</p>
  <pre ng-bind="selected.person | json"></pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

$index won't work as it represents index of loop, not the index of item in array. So to fix this you could have index property in source or you could write a function to return related index.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function(scope) {

  scope.persons = [{
    name: 'ABC index 0'
  }, {
    name: 'EFG index 1'
  }, {
    name: 'XYX index 2'
  }];

  scope.selectedPerson = "1";
  scope.getIndex = function(item) {
    return scope.persons.indexOf(item);
  }
}])

angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
  Selected Person:-
  <pre>{{persons[selectedPerson] | json}}</pre>
  <hr/>
  <table>
    <tr class="restTable" data-ng-repeat="person in persons|orderBy:'name'">
      <td> {{ person.name}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="$parent.selectedPerson" value="{{$parent.getIndex(person)}}" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```